# get the attribute of a link which is in the same div

Tags: jquery, html

how can i get the attribute (href) of a link that is in the same div as another element , see the example below:

```
  <div id="wrap">
      <div id="column1">
         <div class="desc">Some stuff</div>
         <a href="#1" class="url link1">Link1</a>
      </div>
      <div id="column2">
         <div class="desc2">Another Some stuff</div>
         <a href="#" class="url link2">Link2</a>
      <div>
  </div>


  <div id="wrap">
      <div id="column1">
         <div class="desc">Some stuff</div>
         <a href="#2" class="url link1">Link1</a>
      </div>
      <div id="column2">
         <div class="desc2">Another Some stuff</div>
         <a href="#" class="url link2">Link2</a>
      <div>
  </div>
```

When i click **LINK2** of the **first** wrap div , jQuery get the **href of link1** of the **first** wrap div.

I know we can get the href using `.attr()` in jQuery but how can i archive this using jQUery?

Comment: you should not use the duplicate ids

Comment: Are you repeating the same id? The example has two elements with id 'link1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you get the current `<a>` element (Link 2) which has been clicked using `$(this)`, you can get Link1 using this:

`alert( $(this).parent().prev().find('a.link1').attr('href') );`

Answer (score 0):

modify the html remove the duplicate ids and use class instead

```
 <div class="wrap">
      <div id="column1">
         <div class="desc">Some stuff</div>
         <a href="#1" class="url" id="link1">Link1</a>
      </div>
      <div id="column2">
         <div class="desc2">Another Some stuff</div>
         <a href="#" class="url" id="link2">Link2</a>
      <div>
  </div>


  <div class="wrap">
      <div id="column1">
         <div class="desc">Some stuff</div>
         <a href="#2" class="url" id="link1">Link1</a>
      </div>
      <div id="column2">
         <div class="desc2">Another Some stuff</div>
         <a href="#" class="url" id="link2">Link2</a>
      <div>
  </div>
```

jquery

```
$(".wrap").delegate("a","click",function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
    alert($(this).attr("href"));

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Bh5J/1/

Comment: do stoppropagation stops the link functionality? as there's a function assigned to the links when they are clicked

Comment: no that is `preventDefault()`, `stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up the DOM